# Einstein Tensor Notation: Addition inside a function

Tags: tensors

### Main Question

Can I represent addition of multi-dimensional variables in this linear function in Einstein Summation Convention?

$$
f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v})
$$

This didn't seem right $f(x_{\mu}+v_{\mu})$ and nor did $f(x+v)_{\mu}$

#### More Information...

I am doing an unrelated question on multi-dimensional Taylor Series and I wanted to test my knowledge of compact tensor notation.

My full expression is

$$
   f = f(x_1,\cdots,x_N) = f(\mathbf{r})
   \quad\text{and}\quad
   \mathbf{v} = \left(h_1,\cdots,h_N\right)
   \\
   f( \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{v} ) = 
   \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla f( \mathbf{r} )
   + \sum^{N}_{n=2} \frac{1}{n!} \left( \mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \right)^n
   f(\mathbf{r}) + R_N ( \mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v})
$$

I am looking to compactly represent this in tensor notation as I am sure it can be done.

Comment: $f(x+v) = f((x^\mu + v^\mu)e_\mu)$. Einstein notation works only when you are given a basis. Here that basis is $e_\mu$.

Comment: btw what is this $f$ exactly? $f$ from where to where? I assume $f$ is linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tensor notation I assume you just mean [Einstein's summations convention](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html), i.e. the convention where repeated indices are summed over all the coordinates instead of having an explicity sum: $a_ib_i \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$.

The notation $f({\bf x})$ is just a shorthand for $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, i.e. to tell the reader that $f$ takes points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as it's argument. The point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ can be written as the sum $x_\mu e^\mu$ where $e^\mu$ are basis-vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example $e^\mu=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$, however writing $f(x_\mu e^\mu)$ is not standard and can be confusing. You are better off using one of the two standard ways mentioned above with $f({\bf x})$ being the most compact one.

The summation convention is often very useful when doing *calculations*, the final result of such calculations often has a more clear and compact formulation using vector-calculus expressions like $\nabla$, dot-product, $\times$, etc. The notation should be used wisely. Personally I think the formula you have looks better as written than expressed in the summation convention (i.e. ${\bf v}\cdot \nabla f$ is more clear and compact than $v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$) and also note that the sum $\sum_{n=2}^N$ cannot be removed even when using the summation convention (without additional definitions).

Comment: Thanks for a brilliant, well rounded answer. Despite being able to use these constructs in complex topics such as RQFT, often with the pace of new concepts being introduced I do not have time to apply the concepts in unusual formats. Hence the confusion as you see here! May I ask how you would you represent a Hessian of $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)^n$ (in its own right). Would this be correct $v_i\partial_i\partial_jv_j$ with the assumption that $i,j=1,\cdots,n$

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane For $n=2$ we have $[{\bf v}\cdot \nabla]^2 \equiv v_iv_j \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = v_i v_j H_{ij}$ where $H$ is the Hessian of $f$. Some also use the notation $\partial_{i}\partial_{j}f \equiv \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ (note that $v_i$ are constants here so they do not get differentiated and can be moved to the left).

Comment: Ok I see my error. Also it is clear why it may as well be left in the brackets

Answer (score 0):

After discussion with a few course mates we came to the conclusion that it should generally be left as the following,

$$
f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v}) = \cdots
$$

with index notation on other relevant terms.

On the topic of taylor series for tensors there is a really interesting treatment of Taylor's Theorem in Tensor Calculus presented in [this 1929 paper](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-32/1/87.full.pdf).

Comment: So, an unclear question with a pointless answer. And you present downvotes as an evidence of unfriendliness.

Comment: Please keep meta comments on meta. Please explain how if someone is unsure if they can represent $f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{v})= \cdots...$ in tensor notation that this is then completely useless.